# Creating different calculus functions in SML New Jersey

Tags: sml, smlnj

A) Write the function `indefIntegratePoly` which takes a list of coefficients standing for a polynomial (in the order from highest degree to lowest with all terms present) and returns a new list of ​coefficients standing for an indefinite integral of that polynomial. You must use `foldr` (Given below). Assume the constant produced for the anti-derivative representing the indefinite integral is 0.0.

```
fun foldr (f, s, []) = s
 ​ | foldr (f, s, x::rest) = f(x, foldr(f, s, rest));
```

I just want to know where to start, cause I’m struggling to get ant type of function that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> fun foldr (f, s, []) = ...
> ```

The built-in `foldr` resembles this function, but is defined as

```
fun foldr f s [] = ...
```

That is, curried rather than tupled.

I'll assume your version of `foldr` in the below response.

> I just want to know where to start

You could start with

```ml
fun indefIntegratePoly ks =
    let fun f (k, acc) = ...
    in foldr (f, [], ks)
    end
```

where `f` takes a single coefficient and builds a list of integrated coefficients in `acc`.

Note that `foldr` folds from the right to the left, so the first value of `k` is the coefficient for the term with the smallest power. You know how large that power is, since it starts with being 1, and subsequent iterations of the fold represent terms with a power more than that.

If I recall right, *a·x^n* integrates to *(a·x^(n+1))/n*, so for any one term, you must divide by the term's power. This means that the context of `f` must have that available. `acc` can be any type, e.g. *int × int list*, where the first *int* is the current term's power.

Expanding on the template,

```ml
fun indefIntegratePoly ks =
    let fun f (k, (n, iks)) =
            (n+1, ...)
    in #2 (foldr (f, [], (1, ks)))
    end
```

the fold accumulates a pair where `k` is the coefficient for the current term, `n` is the power of the current term, and `iks` is a list of integrated coefficients. Increasing the power of each term (turning the *n* into *n+1* in *a·x^n* → *(a·x^(n+1))/n*) is a matter of adding an extra term to the list, which can be accomplished by initializing the fold with some `[j]` instead of `[]`, where `j` is the coefficient for the constant term *k* as *k* → *k·x^1*.

Since `foldr` now produces a pair, and the `#1` part of this pair is only used during the iteration, while the `#2` part holds the integrated coefficients, the largest power can be discarded by destructuring the pair using `#2`.